# Список массивов Java

Tags: массивы, java, список

Возможен ли доступ к элементам массивов, находящихся в списке ArrayList?

Comment: да, возможен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почему бы нет? Насколько я понял вы хотите сделать что-то типа:

```
package com.sevak_avet.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer[]> a = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

        a.add(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        a.add(new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6 });
        a.add(new Integer[] { 7, 8, 9 });

        System.out.println(a.get(1)[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Изменять элементы точно так же не получается...

a.set(1[1], 100);

Comment: `a.get(1)[1] = 100;`

Comment: Неожиданно, но круто! Спасибо!

Comment: а чего неожиданного? по сути то же самое ((a.get(1))[1]) = 100;



    //1// (a.get(1))//получаем ссылку на массив 
    //2// (наш массив)[1]//получаем ссылку на Integer
    //3// (наш Integer)=100;//присваиваем значение